# Get a list of grouped products with a simple product associate

Tags: magento-1.9

I need get a list of grouped products with a singular product.

For example:

I have the single product A and I have the grouped products B,C,D and E.

Only B and E have the single product A associated.

How can i do this?.

I can retrieve the list of all grouped products and do a bucle to get all associate products and compare with simple product but not is a good practice for the performance I think.

Any idea?.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

**SOLVED:**

I'm recovering the parents id with this:

```
Mage::getResourceSingleton('catalog/product_link')
                            ->getParentIdsByChild($_product->getId(), Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Link::LINK_TYPE_GROUPED)
```

Then i have the all grouped products of a product

Answer (score 0):

**Working Code:-**

```
$associatedProduct = array();
    $products = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
            ->getCollection()
            ->addAttributeToFilter('type_id', array('eq' => 'grouped'));
    foreach ($products as $product) {
        $associatedProduct[] = $product->getTypeInstance(true)->getAssociatedProduct($product);
    }



    foreach ($associatedProduct as $singleProduct) {
        foreach ($singleProduct as $product) {
           echo $product->getName().'<br/>';
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Suppose product A = $simpleproduct.

```
$groupParentsIds = Mage::getResourceSingleton('catalog/product_link')->getParentIdsByChild($simpleproduct->getId(), Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Link::LINK_TYPE_GROUPED);
```

Now you will get all the group parent ids who have associated product A. After that you can load the parent products from their ids according to your requirement.

Hope this helps.

Comment: If u see I answer my ask with "SOLVED" and is the same solution....

Comment: Mark the question as solved.